# Расшифровать код

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Есть задача.

*На вход программе подается число n - количество временных промежутков. Затем идут сами временные промежутки вида `19.00 20.00` и так далее. Суть в том, чтобы узнать, покрывают ли данные временные промежутки время от 8 утра до 8 вечера полностью, если же нет - то сколько будет свободных промежутков.*

***Пример входных данных:***

5

8.50 9.35

17.55 19.40

7.20 7.35

8.10 8.59

20.05 21.50

***Пример выходных данных:***

NO 3

Собственно есть код, но можете пожалуйста объяснить, что происходит в строчках 8-15 и 22-24, буду весьма  благодарен.

```
n = int(input())

mtx = []

mintimeidx = 22222222222
maxtimeidx = -22222222222

for _ in range(n):
    c_expr = [x.split('.') for x in input().split()]

    times = [int(x[0])*60 + int(x[1]) for x in c_expr]
    mtx.append(times)

    mintimeidx = min(mintimeidx, times[0])
    maxtimeidx = max(maxtimeidx, times[1])

pline = [0]*24*60

start_time = 8*60
end_time = 20*60 + 1

for I in mtx:
    for K in range(max(I[0], start_time), min(I[1]+1, end_time)):
        pline[K] = 1

ccont = -1
answ = 0

for I in range(start_time, end_time):
    if (ccont != pline[I]):
        ccont = pline[I]
        if pline[I] == 0:
            answ += 1

if answ == 0:
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO', answ)
```

Comment: А эффективный алгоритм интересует?

Comment: @MBo конечно :)

Comment: Кстати, лучше задать новый вопрос, я туда ответ перенесу, потому что здесь на конкретный вопрос уже ответили.

Comment: @MBo [готово](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1207212/%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d1%83%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

похоже, что

1. сутки разбили на части по 1 минуте (60 * 24 минут)
2. дальше введенные интервалы разбивают на минуты и заполняют сутки из 1) - 1 - минута не входит в введенный интервал, 1 - минута входит в ведённый интервал
3. дальше подсчитывается сколько пустых (нулевых) минутных интервалов осталось

код можно было бы сделать таким:

```
# получить данные
time_ranges = [input().split() for _ in range(int(input()))]

day_minutes = [0] * (24 * 60)

# заполнить минутный интервал
for obj in time_ranges:
    # распарсить начало и конец интервала
    start = list(map(int, obj[0].split('.')))
    finish = list(map(int, obj[1].split('.')))

    # заполнить минутный интервал для заданного временного интервала
    for minute in range(start[0] * 60 + start[1], finish[0] * 60 + finish[1] + 1):
        if 0 <= minute < 24 * 60:
            day_minutes[minute] = 1

# подсчитать пустые интервалы в интервале 8:00 - 20:00
old_minute = 1
count = 0

for index in range(8 * 60, 20 * 60 + 1):
    minute = day_minutes[index]

    if minute == 0 and old_minute == 1:
        count += 1

    old_minute = minute

# вывести результат
print(f"NO {count}" if count != 0 else "YES")
```

Comment: Нет, берется минимум и максимум, соответственно считается сколько пустых интервалов между заполненными в заданном промежутке от 8-00  до 20-00, Интервалы не равны минуте.

Comment: а... ну ок, но было похоже

Comment: Вот теперь по красоте )))