# Алгоритм по нахождению промежутков, не принадлежащих ни одному отрезку

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

*Даны координаты начала и конца отрезков, следует найти количество промежутков координатной прямой, не принадлежащих ни одному отрезку.*

[Код из аналогичной задачи про время:](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1207136/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4?noredirect=1#1207200)

```py
n = int(input())

mtx = []

mintimeidx = 22222222222
maxtimeidx = -22222222222

for _ in range(n):
    c_expr = [x.split('.') for x in input().split()]

    times = [int(x[0])*60 + int(x[1]) for x in c_expr]
    mtx.append(times)

    mintimeidx = min(mintimeidx, times[0])
    maxtimeidx = max(maxtimeidx, times[1])

pline = [0]*24*60

start_time = 8*60
end_time = 20*60 + 1

for I in mtx:
    for K in range(max(I[0], start_time), min(I[1]+1, end_time)):
        pline[K] = 1

ccont = -1
answ = 0

for I in range(start_time, end_time):
    if (ccont != pline[I]):
        ccont = pline[I]
        if pline[I] == 0:
            answ += 1

if answ == 0:
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO', answ)
```

Какие существуют более быстрые алгоритмы по решению данной задачи (или подобных)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм, работающий за `O(nlogn)`, где `n` - количество временных промежутков, независимо от количества элементарных интервалов (ладно здесь минутные, а если секунды или микросекунды?):

Сложить в единый список пары (кортежи или списки), содержащие время и признак `-1` для начала промежутка, `+1` для конца промежутка. Добавить ещё пары для `(8.00, +1)` и `(20.00, -1)` для единоообразной обработки этих концов.

Отсортировать по полю времени (отрицательный признак начала обеспечивает то, что при одинаковом времени конца и начала не будет промежутка нулевой длины)

Счетчик активных промежутков `cnt = -1`

Пройти по списку по порядку, добавляя к `cnt` второе поле пар. Если `cnt` **становится равным нулю** - начался свободный промежуток, увеличиваем счётчик свободных.

[Вот пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1166923/) родственной задачи, только там считаются промежутки с наибольшим покрытием

```
n = int(input())

mtx = []

for i in range(n):
    c_expr = [x.split('.') for x in input().split()]

    times = [int(x[0])*60 + int(x[1]) for x in c_expr]
    mtx.append([times[0], -1])
    mtx.append([times[1], 1])

mtx.append([8*60, 1])
mtx.append([20*60, -1])

mtx.sort()

print(mtx)

cnt = -1
free = 0

for m in mtx:
    cnt += m[1]
    if cnt == 0:
        free += 1

print('свободных ', free)
```